# create a sublist in list, for only one column

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-web-api2

I have two sql records with different Address, I'm trying to make it as one record by using sublist

```
public class spproperty
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Addr{ get; set; }
        public int ID{ get; set; }
    }


List<spproperty> lst = new List<spproperty>();
    lst = db.sp_getDetails(inputParameter).ToList();//gets result from stored procedure as in example
```

Example:

```
Name         Addr              ID
John         Florida           234
John         Arizona           234
```

Expected Output in json from list

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Addresses" : {
    "Addr" : "Florida",
    "Addr" : "Arizona"
  },
    "ID": 234,
  }
]
```

I tried in xelement with dataset it worked, Any suggestions with list

Comment: You could try Linq. With Linq you can group a list. Look at this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9yg2ep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by Name and ID then make the desired formatted list using linq. I think the following code will work for your scenario:

```
var desiredList = lst.GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.Name, ID = x.ID })
                     .Select(x => new
                     {
                         Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                         Addresses = x.Select(y => y.Addr).ToList(),
                         ID = x.FirstOrDefault().ID
                     }).ToList();
```

After that you can convert the result to Json if you want.